# Show 5 li's by clicking the a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a big `ul` list with `li` items. I would like to use JavaScript but I don't know how. How can I make this:

The first 5 's `li` are visible. The rest is hidden. When you click the more button. Every time you click. It offers 5 to li's displayed. I make the html in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/FnBrx/

Thanks for helping guys,

Comment: you should copy-paste the code in the question here, not everyone will click the link to fiddle with the code there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$('li:gt(3)').hide();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
$('.more').on('click', function(){
    $('li:visible:last').nextAll(':lt(4)').show();
});
```

​
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FnBrx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    $('li a:not(:visible)').slice(0,5).show().css('color','red');
    return false;
});​
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FnBrx/8/)

[`.slice(0,5)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) reduces the matched set to only the first five elements

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
$('li').each(function(rowIndex){
   if(rowIndex<=5)
        $(this).show();
    }
else
{
$(this).hide();
}
});
```

and then have a button and on click event implement the same functionality.

Comment: I think OP's "Every time you click. It offers 5 to li's displayed" means each time new 5 ones get displayed, so after 3 clicks 20 displayed li's

Comment: on the button click, implement this $('li:visible:last').nextAll(':lt(4)').show();